# SDK library c/c++ Dropbox

Tags: c++, c, dropbox

I want to get an url to play file media from a dropbox I tested the shared link from the user account with cvlc but it won't work .
how can i generate an url to play media file.

Metadatas don't provide an url to play file it only provide :
https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/

```
{
    "size": "225.4KB",
    "rev": "35e97029684fe",
    "thumb_exists": false,
    "bytes": 230783,
    "modified": "Tue, 19 Jul 2011 21:55:38 +0000",
    "client_mtime": "Mon, 18 Jul 2011 18:04:35 +0000",
    "path": "/Getting_Started.pdf",
    "is_dir": false,
    "icon": "page_white_acrobat",
    "root": "dropbox",
    "mime_type": "application/pdf",
    "revision": 220823
}
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202949615-get-link-to-file-with-metadatas- ]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [/media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media), which returns a direct link to the file contents that works for 4 hours.

Comment: in description you can read  this URL should not be used to display content directly in the browser. so it's like you want to get a preview of a media file and not a persistant media file link to play it

Comment: The warning about not displaying directly in the browser should probably be reworded. That guidance is meant to help prevent "referer" leaks when the content contains links of some sort.